# Given a list of numbers use the four basic operations between them to find another given number

Tags: haskell, countdown

First: My English isn't very good, my apologies :(

So, this is the problem I have to solve:

```
-- Based on a simple math game: given a list of numbers use the four basic 
-- operations (+, -, /, *)  between them to find (or be as close as possible to) 
-- another given number
```

There are examples of my problem but I need be more concrete to resolve and I cant think in "haskell mode", I'm a C++ player :(

So, I have this done:

```
-- Find all possible 2-combinations of the elements of xs.
   pairs :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
   pairs xs = [(x, y) | (x:ys) <- tails xs, y <- ys]

 operations :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int, Char, Int)]
 operations (x, y) =
         [ (x, y, '+', x + y) ] ++
         [ (x, y, '*', x * y) ] ++
         [ (x, y, '-', x - y) | x > y ] ++
         [ (x, y, '/', x `div` y) | x >= y, x `mod` y == 0]
```

I have to implement another function ('solve') to do the following:

'solve' function returns a list with all the resulting nodes to choose a pair of numbers from the list of available numbers and apply the operations that are possible to the selected partner.

I'll have to update the list of available numbers (eliminating those used and adding the new one) and the list of operations (to reflect the latest operation)

Example:

```
solve ( 100 , [1,4,5] , [] )

[ ( 100 , [5,5] , [(1,4,'+',5)] ), -- take first tuple 1,4 add and subs into "new tuple"5,5
( 100 , [3,5] , [(4,1,'-',3)] ),
( 100 , [6,4] , [(1,5,'+',6)] ),
( 100 , [4,4] , [(5,1,'-',4)] ),
( 100 , [9,1] , [(4,5,'+',9)] ),
( 100 , [1,1] , [(5,4,'-',1)] ),
( 100 , [20,1] , [(4,5,'*',20)] ) ]
```

First take a couple of numbers(using pairs function),

Second show `[number,number,'operation',result]` of the 'operations' can do.

I have something like this:

```
solve(n,ns) = [ e | ns' <- pairs ns
                  , e   <- operations ns']
```

But I can't make it work,any idea??

---

Edit:

I really appreciate your answer,Thank you so much, but If I can't do the function I'm asking for I can't understand your development because I'm really really new in Haskell :(

As I say, I need a function that with a list of numbers and the 2 operations I wrote in the main post (operations and pairs) make another function to do this:

Example)

```
solve ( 100 , [1,4,5] , [] )

[ ( 100 , [5,5] , [(1,4,'+',5)] ),
( 100 , [3,5] , [(4,1,'-',3)] ),
( 100 , [6,4] , [(1,5,'+',6)] ),
( 100 , [4,4] , [(5,1,'-',4)] ),
( 100 , [9,1] , [(4,5,'+',9)] ),
( 100 , [1,1] , [(5,4,'-',1)] ),
( 100 , [20,1] , [(4,5,'*',20)] ) ]
```

Thank you so much for the quickly answer but I need more specific in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really neat problem, but somewhat trickier than it might seem at first.

We want to, for the mathematical operations `'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'`, and `'/'`

```
data Op = Plus | Minus | Mult | Div deriving (Eq, Ord)

ops = [Op]
ops = [Plus, Minus, Div, Mult]

instance Show Op where
  show Plus  = "+"
  show Minus = "-"
  show Div   = "/"
  show Mult  = "*"
```

and a set of numbers `ns`, search all possible arithmetic expressions that use each number exactly once for the expression which is closest to some goal. To solve this, we'll express the problem abstractly, then solve it in a way that's clearly correct, then apply some optimizations.

---

Let's think of what kind of data type could represent our expression. Each term, call it `Term`, needs to be *either* the combination of an `Op` and the two other `Terms` its acting on, *or* a "pure" value, an integer which just is itself.

```
data Term = Ap Op Term Term | Pure Double
```

such that we have `(2 + (3 * 4))` represented as `App Plus (Pure 2) (App Mult (Pure 3) (Pure 4))`. Given such a `Term`, we could traverse it recursively to print it out or to compute the result.

```
instance Show Term where
  show (Pure x)    = show x
  show (Ap op l r) = "(" ++ show l ++ " " ++ show op ++ " " ++ show r ++ ")"
```

We'll investigate this in more detail in due time, but for now we need to focus on generation.

---

Given any number in our list of numbers `n <- ns`, we can construct a `Term` which involves it in three different ways, either `Pure n`, `Term op n other`, or `Term op other n` where `op` is one of our `ops` and `other` is a term constructed from numbers in `Data.List.delete n ns` (`ns` without `n`). This is a perfectly valid recursive definition of all `Terms` you could possible construct from `ns`. Let's build it.

First we'll need a way of selecting or "focusing" on each element in `ns`. We'll do this by forming a zipper through `ns` as `pares :: [a] -> [([a], a, [a])]` which turns a list into a list of triples, one for each element in the original list. The middle element is the "focused" value, the left list are the elements which were on the left side of our focused value and the right list are the values that were on the right side. This might seem like overkill, but it'll come in handy later.

```
pare :: [a] -> Int -> ([a], a, [a])
pare xs n = pare' n ([], xs) -- accumulate the left and right sides
  where
    -- we end up storing the left list in reverse, which is the style of zippers
    -- it seems a little weird, but it makes the code very simple and it shouldn't
    -- affect our problem
    pare' 0 (left, x:right) = (left, x, right)
    pare' n (left, x:right) = pare' (n-1) (x:left, right)

-- 'pare' is a little dangerous since it can have out of bounds errors,
-- but 'pares' can not.
pares :: [a] -> [([a], a, [a])]
pares xs = map (pare xs) [0..length xs - 1]
```

and now we can call `pares [1,2,3]` to get

```
[ ( []    , 1 ,  [2,3] )
, ( [1]   , 2 ,  [3]   )
, ( [2,1] , 3 ,  []    ) ]
```

From here it's a straightforward definition, `allTerms :: [Double] -> [Term]`, using `List` comprehensions.

```
allTerms ns =
  [ result
  | (left, n, right) <- pares ns
  , result <- Pure n : (concat [ [ Ap op (Pure n) term, Ap op term (Pure n) ]
                               | op   <- ops
                               , term <- allTerms (left ++ right)
                               ])
  ]
```

Okay, so not so straightfoward. Since we always want to return "at least" the `(Pure n)` `Term`, we have to separate out our list comprehension that handles the recursive terms. Otherwise, we get `[]` as the result always since the list fails to return any recursive subterms for `allTerms []`.

This notation is a little difficult, so let's change it to `Monad`ic notation, as all `List` comprehensions can be transformed to uses of the `List` `Monad`.

```
allTerms ns = do
  (left, n, right) <- pares ns
  let branches = do
        op <- ops
        term <- allTerms (left ++ right)
        [ Ap op (Pure n) term, Ap op term (Pure n) ]
  Pure n : branches
```

`do` notation lets us strip off some unnecessary brackets and gives us a better ground for optimizations later. For now, we can just test the thing.

```
*Main> mapM_ print $ allTerms [1,2]
1.0
(1.0 + 2.0)
(2.0 + 1.0)
(1.0 - 2.0)
(2.0 - 1.0)
(1.0 / 2.0)
(2.0 / 1.0)
(1.0 * 2.0)
(2.0 * 1.0)
2.0
(2.0 + 1.0)
(1.0 + 2.0)
(2.0 - 1.0)
(1.0 - 2.0)
(2.0 / 1.0)
(1.0 / 2.0)
(2.0 * 1.0)
(1.0 * 2.0)
```

It should be easy to check that this is... well, comprehensive. It also demonstrates a weakness in our definition---we ignored lots of the symmetry of the problem. For instance, it's not necessary to generate subterms for a number which we've already visited (those terms will be generated by later terms again. Furthermore, when the `op` is `Plus` or `Mult`, we can take advantage of commutativity. It's a quick rewrite to fix this.

```
allTerms ns = do
  (left, n, right) <- pares ns
  let branches = do
        op <- ops
        term <- allTerms right -- we no longer visit the left terms
                               -- this is the value of using 'pares'
        makeApps op (Pure n) term
  Pure n : branches
  where
    -- makeApps only applies symmetry when the operator is Div or
    -- Minus.
    makeApps Plus t1 t2 = [Ap Plus t1 t2]
    makeApps Mult t1 t2 = [Ap Mult t1 t2]
    makeApps op   l  r  = [Ap op l r, Ap op r l]
```

If `ns = [1,2,3]` then our first version would generate 195 `Term`s. The second one takes advantage of symmetry to generate only 57 `Term`s. This is somewhat reasonable, so let's keep moving forward.

---

So now that we've generated all of the possible `Term`s, we need to evaluate them. Like our `Show` instance this is a relatively simple recursive definition.

```
calcTerm :: Term -> Double
calcTerm (Pure x) = x
calcTerm (Ap Plus  l r) = calcTerm l + calcTerm r
calcTerm (Ap Minus l r) = calcTerm l - calcTerm r
calcTerm (Ap Mult  l r) = calcTerm l * calcTerm r
calcTerm (Ap Div   l r) = calcTerm l / calcTerm r
```

Let's say we're looking for the `Term` which has a value closest to `goal :: Double`. We can annotate every `Term` `t` with its "error", `abs (goal - calcTerm t)` then sort by that. We'll need to use the specialized `sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]` from `Data.List`.

```
import Data.List (sortBy)

bestTerm :: Double -> [Term] -> (Double, Term)
bestTerm g =
  minimumBy (\(a, _) (b, _) -> a `compare` b)
  . map (\t -> (abs (g - calcTerm t), t))
```

Or, using some specialized functions `Control.Arrow.&&&` and `Data.Ord.comparing` we can write most quickly

```
bestTerm :: Double -> [Term] -> (Double, Term)
bestTerm g =
  minimumBy (comparing fst) . map (first error) where error t = abs (g - calcTerm t)
```

and we can begin to answer the question

```
*Main> bestTerm 31 $ allTerms [1..5]
(0.0,(1.0 + ((3.0 * (4.0 * 5.0)) / 2.0)))
```

but only sometimes, since waiting on `length $ allTerms [1..10]` defeats my patience. It looks like there are `(7^n-1)/6` terms on `n` numbers (See [Sloane](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C8%2C57%2C400%2C2801%2C19608%2C137257%2C960800&language=english&go=Search)) so we'd be waiting on it to compute 47,079,208 `Term`s.

---

Hopefully this demonstrates how you could go about computing the answer to your problem and also gives you amble locations to search for ways to optimize the result.

And I think the answer to your example is `(79.0, (1.0 + (4.0 * 5.0)))`

Comment: Nice solution tel.

Note that the technique used to create the `Term` expressions and then evaluate them is known more generally as an algebra. FPComplete has a nice article on these here: [link](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/bartosz/understanding-algebras)

Comment: I originally wrote out the whole thing just to play around with evaluating `Term`s as `Fix`edpoints of a carrier `Functor`. I was hoping there'd be a clever ana/cata optimization or derivation that would make the whole thing clearer... but then I toned all that stuff down when the majority of the time was spent just searching terms.

Comment: I  really appreciate the answer but it's more complex to me right now.
I edit my main post to explain really what I need, it just the 'solve' operation because without this I can't follow my work. Thanks again guys!